# What is the use of raw Data Type in R

Tags: r

What is the practical use of raw data type in R ?

I have read the documentation, however, I am not able to understand a practical scenario where I would make use of raw data type.

Comment: [Here is the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/raw.html) for `base::raw`

Comment: Text encoding and conversion seems like a possible use case.

Comment: Two examples where I have used it is when getting base64 encoded data from a SOAP API, then converting it to a more useful format.  I have also used it when receiving binary files, that are then written to disk.  Basically any time you have binary data.